# HTMLCollection is empty when I loop over it

Tags: javascript

I am fetching some HTML elements using the `document.getElementsByClassName` function. However I seem to stumble upon a problem. When I try to loop over these elements, there doesn't seem to be any items. I have tried converting the collection to an array using `Array.from` but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

```js
var videos = document.getElementsByClassName("ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer")
console.log(videos)

videos = Array.from(videos)
console.log(videos)
```

[image: output]

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* collection ... perhaps the elements don't exist yet when you `Array.from` - the console can be misleading - hover over the blue *i* to understand why you can see elements in the first log output

Comment: For context this is a chrome extension. I'm using `"run_at": "document_idle"`, which should make it run as soon as the DOM is ready. I tried adding the following code to make sure the DOM has been fully loaded. Does not seem to do the trick though

```
if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
  console.log("document is already ready, just execute code here");
  inject();
} else {
  console.log("document is not ready, set event listener");
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", inject);
}
```

Comment: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", inject)` should work fine. Id all of your `<script>` tags located at the bottom of HTML -- before the closing `</body>` tag?